# Validation ignored when cloning a newly created record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I have a model `UserFile` that `belongs_to` a `Folder`:

```
class UserFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment
  belongs_to :folder

  validates_attachment_presence :attachment
  validates_presence_of :folder_id

  def copy(target_folder)
    new_file = self.clone
    new_file.folder = target_folder
    new_file.save!
  end
end
```

The following test fails unexpectedly:

```
test 'cannot copy a file to anything other than a folder' do
  folder = Factory(:folder)
  file1 = UserFile.create(:attachment => File.open("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/textfile.txt"), :folder => Folder.root)
  file2 = UserFile.find(file1)

  # Should pass, but fails
  assert_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) { file1.copy(nil) }

  # Same record, but this DOES pass
  assert_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) { file2.copy(nil) }

  assert file1.copy(folder)
end
```

The `validates_presence_of :folder_id` is ignored when using a newly created object, but when I do an `ActiveRecord#find` it DOES work. I think it has something to do with calling `clone` in the `copy` method, but I cannot figure it out. Does anyone know what is going on or how to make the test pass??

Comment: `file1` is an instance of UserFile but for `file2` you are using `UserFile.find(file1)`, i think is `UserFile.find(file1.id)`

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can either use `UserFile.find(file1.id)` or `UserFile.find(file1)`. It's the same thing.

Comment: Is it raising an exception for the reason you think it is?  Perhaps, your validation is not working in either case, but a different validation is failing on the 2nd save -- due to a duplicate value in a unique column, perhaps?

Comment: In the first case it SHOULD raise an exception, but it doesn't. I verified that `file1.valid? == true`, which should not be the case. I also checked that after calling `new_file.save!` in the `copy` method `new_file.persisted? == true`, which should not be possible because of the validation. In this second case it raises an exception as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mischa, 
cloning is a beast.

record.errors is memoized and the @errors instance variable gets cloned too.

```
file1.errors = new_file.errors
```

this will be non-nil since `create` called validations on `file1`.

now what happens when you clone file1 and say `new_file.save!`?
Deep inside `valid?` calls errors.clear on new_file but it still points to the same error object as file1.
Now viciously, the presence validator is implemented like this:

```
def validate(record)
   record.errors.add_on_blank(attributes, options)
end
```

which (obviously) can only access errors.base
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors/add_on_blank

so, although, the validations do run on new_file as the record, the presence validation passes since

```
new_file.errors.instance_eval { @base } == file1
```

and for `file1.folder_id` is NOT blank.

Now, your second test passes because if you read the file entry from the db, `file2.errors` is nil so when you clone it and call validations on the clone, the errors object is created anew with the correct base (the clone) for which `folder_id` will be blank because of the line `new_file.folder = target_folder`.

your problem is solved by simply adding

```
def copy(target_folder)
    new_file = self.clone
    new_file.instance_eval { @errors = nil } # forces new error object on clone
    new_file.folder = target_folder
    new_file.save!
end
```

hope this helped

Comment: Thanks!! I will try if your solution works. If it does, I will try to understand the reasoning behind it ;-)

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot. This was driving me crazy. I am reading up on memoization and trying to completely understand your explanation.

Comment: memoisation is just this bit: `def errors
  @errors ||= Errors.new(self)
end`, the viscious thing is that validations take the record from errors base, which is idiotic and non-transparent i think given that validations have record passed to them. but rails core devs might say: clone at your own peril :)

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your explanations and great answer. I am sorry I can only upvote it once...

Comment: Boa... that sucks! Spent myself about 2 hours and didn't get further.. thanks for this help..

Comment: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/11/12/ann-rails-3-2-9-has-been-released/: Fix AR#dup to nullify the validation errors in the dup'ed object. Previously the original and the dup'ed object shared the same errors.

Comment: @ViktorTrón I only noticed your comment about the bugfix now. I guess I don't need this workaround anymore. Will try. Thanks again.